# How to optimize speed for multiple CURL get requests in PHP?

Tags: php, api, laravel, curl, optimization

I'm connecting to an API with PHP through a CURL GET and I receive a json with almost 5000 orders. For every order I make another CURL GET and receive the order details (basically 2 foreach). After that I make some inserts and updates in the database (basic stuff) with LARAVEL.

The big problem is that for those 5000 orders I have a loading time of almost one hour. I need to this with a cron every night (and for more than 5000).

I have a cloud solution with 2GB Memory and 2 CoreProcessor.

I tried also Zebra Curl but cannot use that with curl in curl request.

Comment: 1) Does this CRON have to run once a day to grab 5000? Can it run hourly to grab ~200 orders instead? My suggestion would be to have it run multiple times an hour if possible, add to a queue, then have another CRON that processes the queue at a steady rate.

Comment: You can use multi-curl to perform multiple downloads at one time.

Comment: This is just one organization with 5000 orders. I need 40-50 organizations - every night. It's an intresting idea grabbing ~200 in queue. @yergo: the second curl needs something from the response of the first curl - I cannot use the multi-curl.

Comment: You can use single curl to download orders list, and than in multi-curl download specific order per request. Either its doable or you have providen too few information. Maybe you can share some bits of code and requests structure so I can help further?

Comment: I'm assuming there's some kind of identifier in your API request to only return results since a certain ID or timestamp. If that's the case then you can set this to run every 15 minutes, and it will grab around 50 rows. Then your CRON can run every minute to processes 2-3 per run. That way processing is spread out over the day, rather than doing a really intense bit once a day.

Comment: @yergo thank you for the info, I should try that multi-curl for the details, I hope it will be faster, I never used that. Jamie: That's too risky - making this every day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if 2% of the daily jobs (1 of 50 organisations) takes almost 4% of a day you definitely need parallel processing.

There are several solutions for that:

- Run a cron job for each organisation.
- Process entries for multiple companies in 1 multi-curl call.
- Use multiple servers.

I would probably use the first one: You could have a cron job check (every minute?) which organisations still need to be processed and which organisations are being processed at the moment and pick one if there are any left.

That way each job would still take 1 hour but all would be processed in the time-span of 2 hours each night.